# Best way to call out important content to screen readers?

Tags: usability, accessibility

We're adding new content to our page that describes the accessibility options available at a destination. The user may make accessibility requests via checkbox inputs (bathroom, hearing-impaired equipment, etc.) but we're now providing a disclaimer for things that cannot be reserved online (braille, accessible parking, etc.)

As this is geared specifically towards people with accessibility needs, what's the best way to call out this content to a screen reader?

Answer (score 1):

Create jump to content links http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/

Use proper HTML5 tags relevant to the content. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595719/html5-main-element-versus-aria-landmark-role-main  Use Aria Landmark roles. http://a11yproject.com/posts/aria-landmark-roles/

More information on Aria attributes and usages http://webdesign.about.com/od/accessibility/a/wai-aria.htm

Comment: These are excellent links, and I am familiar with semantic tags and ARIA. Do you know of an appropriate ARIA role to call out visible, non-interactive content?

Comment: The main and article roles seems to be the absolute strongest of them all.

Answer (score -1):

I have used aria-label and aria-labelledby. Though i am not an expert in AX